# How to create a distributed java server

Tags: java, udp, distributed-computing

How would you create a distributed and easily extendable java server.
I have created an audio repeater which receives and resends audio packets via UDP, however i would like to be able to balance the users over several servers.
What would you suggest?
The server works in the following basic way:
user registers in a room, then starts either listening for messages from the server or sends audio packets to the room. When the server receives a packet it looks for the ip addresses of the users that are in the room and resends them the audio packets.

Comment: do you want a room limited to one server or do you want to distribute a room over several servers as well?

Comment: The rooms will be on one server(as they will have 20 users at most), however I also have to manage a centralized list of who is where and the clients need to also know to which server to send the data. I have some ideas but maybe somebody has already done something similar.

Comment: yeah, sounds like a neat project you got there! If I had more time, I would jump on board. I have lots of ideas, but no experience in distributed computing.

Comment: cool kids these days are using Akka for distributed stuff and Netty for sockets. might want to take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that new rooms are created relatively infrequently, even if there are a lot of rooms, a lot of servers, and a lot of clients looking for the rooms, I would recommend [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/). Do as follows:

- A server creates a node for each room with the room's name containing the server address. You can even guarantee that at most one server claims each room (see locking recipes in the documentation).
- A client reads the node with the desired name, obtaining the address of the corresponding server. Such read operations will be load-balanced across servers, making it scale.

As a second step, you can even make your servers fault-tolerant by using ephemeral nodes that are watched by other (stand-by?) servers, claiming the rooms if the original server fails.